# Почему obj.SetActive(true); не работает?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class firstone : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj;
    void Start()
    {
        obj.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)){
            obj.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

У меня есть куб и для него вот такой код. В начале сцены он отключается, но по нажатию space включаться не хочет. В чем проблема и как решить?

Comment: Читай описания в документации и найдешь ответы на большинство вопросов.  [GameObject.SetActive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
obj.SetActive(false);
```

отключает скрипт полностью.

Т.к. код в скрипте становится неактивным, то и `Update()` в коде не вызывается.

Что бы иметь возможность включить по нажатой клавише - необходимо создать внешний скрипт на внешнем включенном обьекте который будет включать этот обьект извне.